# Is there a better way to fetch total count with filters for pagination Mysql?

Tags: mysql, pagination

Currently I am fetching total count using union with my original query, so that the filters of query can be applied in count too.
currently my **query structure** is:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        MUI.USERNAME,MUI.NAME,MUI.STATUS,MUI.BILLING_TYPE,MUI.BILLING_SUBTYPE,MSU.USER_NAME AS SELLER_USERNAME,MUA.ADDRESS,MUCN.CONTACT_NUMBER,MUI.CNIC,
            CASE
                WHEN MUI.BILLING_SUBTYPE = 'VAR' THEN 'Variable'
                WHEN MUI.BILLING_SUBTYPE = 'DATE' THEN 'Fixed'
                ELSE MUI.BILLING_SUBTYPE
            END AS BILLING_TYPE_READABLE
    FROM
        USER_INFO MUI
    LEFT JOIN SYSTEM_ENTITY MSE ON MSE.ID = MUI.SELLER_ID
    LEFT JOIN SYSTEM_USER MSU ON MSE.ID = MSU.ENTITY_ID
    LEFT JOIN USER_CONTACT_NUMBER MUCN ON MUCN.ACCOUNT_ID_FK = MUI.ACCOUNT_ID AND MUCN.CONTACT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY'
    LEFT JOIN USER_ADDRESS MUA ON MUA.ACCOUNT_ID_FK = MUI.ACCOUNT_ID
    WHERE
        MUI.SELLER_ID IN (1)
            AND MUI.STATUS <> 'Terminated'
    GROUP BY MUI.USERNAME UNION SELECT 
        'TOTAL_COUNT',FOUND_ROWS(),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) TEMP
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN USERNAME = 'TOTAL_COUNT' THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END , USERNAME
LIMIT 101 OFFSET 0;
```

This works fine for me but takes too much time due to which my API throw an error of timeout during its execution. Is there any better way to deal with this situation?

*I don't want total rows count in table, I want to fetch number of rows which will return by above query without limit*

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has a special feature for this.  Do:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS rest of your query with a limit
```

and then

```
select FOUND_ROWS();
```

to get the number of rows that would have been returned if the first query had no limit.

This is deprecated as of mysql 8.0.17, however, and may be removed from a future version.

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` also return in almost same amount of time as current solution of mine with `FOUND_ROWS`. Is there any other way to more optimize the query?

Comment: you aren't going to get any faster than `select count(*) from (select rest-of-your-basic-query-with-no-limit) foo`; if that's too slow as is, all you can do is try improving it: add to your question output of `show create table ....` for all the tables in the query and `explain select ... rest-of-your-basic-query-with-no-limit`